# Error: suffix or operands invalid for `push'

Tags: compilation, fortran

I'm trying to compile someone else's Fortran code and getting strange compiler errors. In particular, I get errors like this:

```
pgf77 -c -pc 64 -g77libs hpair.f
/tmp/dstolars/pgf77kdVzoC: Assembler messages:
/tmp/dstolars/pgf77kdVzoC:12: Error: suffix or operands invalid for `push'
/tmp/dstolars/pgf77kdVzoC:7559: Error: suffix or operands invalid for `push'
/tmp/dstolars/pgf77kdVzoC:7818: Error: suffix or operands invalid for `push'
```

There were not any files in `/tmp/dstolars/pgf77kdVzoC`.

Here is my makefile

```
OBJS = hpair.o Cteq61Pdf.o mrst2001.o

LIBS = $(CERN)/libpdflib804.a $(CERN)/libpawlib.a $(CERN)/libgrafX11.a $(CERN)/libpacklib.a         $(CERN)/libmathlib.a $(CERN)/libkernlib.a

FFLAGS= -pc 64 -g77libs

FC=pgf77

# Commands:
.f.o:
    $(FC) -c $(FFLAGS) $*.f

hpair: $(OBJS)
    $(FC) $(FFLAGS) $(OBJS) $(LIBS) -o run

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS)
```

When I do `make --just-print` I get

```
pgf77 -c -pc 64 -g77libs hpair.f
pgf77 -c -pc 64 -g77libs Cteq61Pdf.f
pgf77 -c -pc 64 -g77libs mrst2001.f
pgf77 -pc 64 -g77libs hpair.o Cteq61Pdf.o mrst2001.o /afs/cern.ch/sw/lcg/hepsoft/0.9/x86_64-slc6-gcc47-opt/share/cernlib/libpdflib804.a /afs/cern.ch/sw/lcg/hepsoft/0.9/x86_64-slc6-gcc47-opt/share/cernlib/libpawlib.a /afs/cern.ch/sw/lcg/hepsoft/0.9/x86_64-slc6-gcc47-opt/share/cernlib/libgrafX11.a /afs/cern.ch/sw/lcg/hepsoft/0.9/x86_64-slc6-gcc47-opt/share/cernlib/libpacklib.a /afs/cern.ch/sw/lcg/hepsoft/0.9/x86_64-slc6-gcc47-opt/share/cernlib/libmathlib.a /afs/cern.ch/sw/lcg/hepsoft/0.9/x86_64-slc6-gcc47-opt/share/cernlib/libkernlib.a -o run
```

Comment: Would you post the output of `make --just-print`?

Comment: I'm a bit skeptical about the target `.f.o`.

Comment: @NickThompson I added that. Not sure about the .f.o thing.

Comment: Can you push this code to a public GitHub repo?

Comment: @NickThompson The code is called HPair and can be found at http://tiger.web.psi.ch/hpair/